# How to extract the audo track from an m4a file?

Tags: video, audio, arch-linux, m4a

I've got an m4a video file and would like to extract the sound. How can I do that? Running Arch Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way to do it is, if you have mplayer:

```
mplayer video.m4a -ao pcm
```

the audio will be in a file called `audiodump.wav'

You can encode that to an mp3 with `lame -V2  audiodump.wav'

Answer (score 1):

Interesting – typically the `.m4a` (MP4 Audio) extension is not used for files with video tracks...

This will extract the audio track in its original form (`-acodec copy`) and discard video (`-vn`):

```
ffmpeg -i video.m4a -acodec copy -vn audio.m4a
```